# issues with Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am back with another question. In this condition i have added two events which is Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_ALL_EVENT but now problem is with SHOW_ALL_EVENT.
Whenever the SHOW_ALL_EVENT occur both the event are triggered.

```
OpenanotherPanel.prototype.onSelectionEvent = function(event) {
    var currSelection = this.viewer.getSelection();
    alert("Something is isolatied");
};
OpenanotherPanel.prototype.nothingToDo = function(event) {
    var currSelection = this.viewer.getSelection();
    alert("Nothing to do");
};
OpenanotherPanel.prototype.load = function() {
    alert('OpenanotherPanel is loaded!');
    this.onSelectionBinded = this.onSelectionEvent.bind(this);
    this.nothingToDoBinded = this.nothingToDo.bind(this);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, this.onSelectionBinded);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_ALL_EVENT, this.nothingToDoBinded);
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know and we were able to reproduce the issue - will check with Engineering to fix this... Meanwhile as a workaround you could easily tell whether `ISOLATE_EVENT` is incorrectly triggered as the `nodeIdArray` would be an empty array

Comment: ISOLATE_EVENT working as expected. I verified that nodeIdarry is not empty.

Comment: What IDs did you get in the array then? Can you set up a live/minimally reproducible example that we can look into (on jsbin/codepen etc)?

Comment: instead of event right now i am using button control, and its working fine